# Why is my javascript function not found by the page it is embedded in?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have a page that has a simple javascript in the header portion of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doLogout() {
        var conf = confirm("Really log out?");
        if (conf === true) {      //changed == to === for boolean comparison
            $.post("logout.aspx");
        }
    }
</script>
```

It uses jQuery to do an AJAX post to my logout page.  The only issue right now is that when I click on the link (`<a href="#" onclick="doLogout();">logout</a>`) to fire this function, nothing happens.  I checked FireBug's console, and it told me that the function is not defined.  This has happened to me before, but I think I botched a bunch of code to fix it *sometimes*.

Does anyone know the proper way to fix this issue?

## Edit

After doing a lot of googling and trying different things, I found this very [concise and informative post](http://forums.asp.net/p/1155910/1899157.aspx). Apparently, as the linked article states, the way the script is referenced in the web site is important as it won't run properly otherwise!  Hopefully this information will be useful for more people.

Comment: Have you checked this is not a cache issue, i.e. the browser holding an old version of your page HTML?

Comment: Yes, that was one of the first things I checked.

Answer (score 5):

This can also occur if there is a syntax error earlier in your javascript code.  Often this will just be interpreted as the function not existing (nor any function AFTER the error).  Check the code above this code (if there is any) and this code for syntax errors.

A way to tell if the cache error is it is to open Firebug and view the Script source.  If the page was cached, you won't see your code.   If it loaded but has syntax errors, the code will show, though it won't "find" it.

Comment: +1 Additionally, a way to protect against this (aside from making sure your javascript works!) is to divide logical sections into separate scripts.

Comment: Unfortunately, the syntax is correct. Viewing the source through firebug's source view is identical (save for the dynamic content) to the source I have in VS2008.

Comment: That is exactly what I put it through. the only thing it complained about was the $. declaration (which is part of jQuery, which functions oddly enough).

Comment: replace the $ with "jQuery" or whatever the "proper" one is (i forget) and see if that cleans it up.  I doubt it though.

Answer (score 2):

Things to test:

1) Can you call this function from something else?  Like add a `<script>` at the bottom of the page to call it?

2) Does the page validate?  Sometimes I get screwy javascript errors if there is some busted HTML like a missing `</b>`

3) I've been starting to wrap my javascript in `<![CDATA[  ]]>` just incase I've got goofy chars in my javascript.

4) I assume you've tested this in other browsers and have the same behavior, right?

5) If you haven't installed it already, install the [Web Developer](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) firefox addon.  It has a nifty toolbar menu that will disable the cache for you so everything reloads.

6) As weird as it sounds, I once hit a javascript issue that was because of how my text editor was saving UTF-8 files.  I forget the details, but it was adding some byte-order-mark or something that upset the browser.

Comment: 1) renamed it, same result (with new name, of course).
2) validated the generated source @ http://validator.w3.org/.
3) can you elaborate on wrapping?
4) Tested in IE7 and FF3.
5) One of my addons I cannot live without, along with FireBug :D
So far, nothing has worked :(

Comment: oops, by wrapping i mean CDATA.  looks like the original comment striped it out :-)

You know what else?  I once it a bug where the fact the file was saved as UTF-8 pissed things off.  Like it put that byte order mark in or something like that.  I forget.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately, I am still getting this error.  I hate being a programmer sometimes haha.

Comment: heh, i know the feeling.  what if you rip out the code and put in a JS file?  Can you create another function in the header and call that?  What if you move the function somewhere else in the HTML, like the footer?

Comment: I just tried putting it into its own 'scripts.js' file, in the root dir of my app. Included it just like every other JS file, and I am still getting the damn "splunge does not exist" from firebug ( i changed doLogout to splunge to make sure the name wasnt already in use )

Comment: To clarify, "just like every other JS file" means just the typical <script src="scripts.js" type="text/javascript" /> etc.

Comment: And I should also add that I've tried moving it from the <head> portion into the footer, and on top of the content as well. same result regardless of the javascript's position.

Comment: yeah, i ment shove it into an external file.  Otherwise... man.  Good luck :-)  gotta love this stuff.

Comment: yeah no kidding. thanks for your tips, ill post back here if i resolve this annoying issue.

Comment: seriously though... UTF8 and CR/LF crap.  who knows.  both have bit me on at least one occasion :-)

Comment: i just used a JS compressor (http://javascriptcompressor.com/) on the function. When trying to call the now-compressed-function, it throws no errors but nothing happens. very strange...

Comment: I found this page because I had the same issue of a function not recognized and throwing an error. I had been through all the same motions. Then I decided to create a new function with just an alert and a console.log inside. It does not throw an error, but does nothing. Gremlins, I tell you :(

Answer (score 1):

I've had this occur when the page had been cached and so it didn't load the new script in. So to fix it clear all private data from Firefox. Not sure if that helps but it sure happened to me a bunch.

Comment: Yes I tried that before posting this question. Thanks for the useful tip nonetheless; I am even surprised at how much that can solve sometimes.

Comment: SHIFT + F5 will force-reload everything on a page, btw.

Comment: Shift+F5 is not something I had even considered, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might occur if you have NoScript. You should check and make sure it's not blocking said script.

Comment: The only stupid question is no question, but I do not have any noscript tags in my code.

Comment: Ahh. No, I do not run that addon.

Answer (score 0):

Other ideas for you to test:

1. is the function defined in the DOM tab in FireBug?
2. if you call doLogout() from the FireBug console, what happens?
3. I assume this is not the only script on that page. Make sure that some later script is not modifying `doLogout` to something else

Comment: It does not look like my function is defined in the DOM tab. What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Did you check the rest of your script to make sure nothing is overriding it? I created a test page with just the code you posted. If you try that, does it work?

Comment: it might be more beneficial to know how and when javascript will override a particular function.  I doubt that this is occurring as I changed my function's name to 'splunge', which is from RAB.

Comment: if it comes later in the script, it will override it.

Comment: i would try removing the comment. if the newlines aren't understood properly, the entire function is being read as if its one line. if so, your comment is getting rid of part of the code, and the function wouldn't be loaded in to the dom. alot of if's there :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried all that's been suggested here without success.

The only way I fixed it was by discovering that in the `<script src="jquery.js">` tag I was using in the head of the page I forgot to close it with its **`</script>`** causing the page to ignore all Javascript functions. So please check that your includes look like:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

I hope that helps. Ross.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DevExpress controls these links may help you: [How to register and execute a JavaScript downloaded to the client via a callback](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E1138) and [How to register and execute a JavaScript downloaded to the client via a callback (standalone JS file)](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E4662) and [Executing javascripts from user controls dynamically created through ASPxCallback panels](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18783)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and discovered the problem was just a wrong case letter inside the name.

Call: filterCheckbox()

vs

function filterCheckBox() {}

problem: lowercase "box" vs uppercase "Box".

So check if the name is exactly the same.